# Unknown storage engine 'XtraDB'

Tags: mysql, percona, storage-engine, percona-server, xtradb

I installed Percona Server 5.6.12-rc60.4, when I want create table such as :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`table` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`title` VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) 
) ENGINE = XtraDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

this error occurred:

```
 #1286 - Unknown storage engine 'XtraDB'
```

How can I create a table with XtraDB engine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XtraDB replaces InnoDB (it's compatible and a drop in replacement), so just add `ENGINE = InnoDB`

However, it should be the default in MySQL 5.5.x onwards

Comment: Using Engine=XtraDB works on 5.5. Don't know why not on 5.6. (Yes, using Engine=InnodB is equivalent)